# .NET 7 (core) - AKS, Application Insights and GCDump memory not adding up

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I have a .NET 7 API deployed on AKS instrumented via Application Insights SDK. Others instances of the same API on the same AKS are using an avg of ~200MB, this one is not that light.

This fact points me to a memory leak triggered by some behavior or race condition.

The problem here is:

- Application Insights reports that the application is using ~500 MB of memory
- AKS reports that the pod is using ~750mb
- `dotnet-gcdump` reports 21MB total
- `dotnet-dump` top 3 largest pools are 21MB (3214 instances of free memory - fragmentation), 16MB (8099 instances of byte[]) and 7MB (40k+ instances of strings). It also reports that the 6th largest object is about 750kb and the 21st is smaller than 100kb...

now... how can I "conciliate" all this info? who is telling the truth?

**Extra Info:**

- This memory hike happened a couple of days ago. For about 4 days everything was OK, suddenly the overall memory spiked to 1.3GB and about 1 minute later it was reclaimed back to 500MB. check it out:
  [image]

Comment: There are multiple possibilities here. The ones I can think of - 1) unmanaged memory leak (so as far as I understand `dotnet-...` will be useless here) 2) AFAIK after memory spike the OS and/or .NET VM will not reclaim the process memory as soon as it is not actually needed by the process JIC in case it will need it soon, so if you have not waited long enough possibly this can be the issue. So in short - all of them can be telling the truth =)

Comment: @GuruStron pls check edits!